# .Batch or .VBS (Win_Server_2003)

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I have two .csv files: inputfile.csv and mainfile.csv

I need to write a script that:

1- will read one by one all the records in inputfile.csv

2- then find if there is a match in the mainfile.csv

3- if there is a match then do nothing and read the next record from inputfile.csv

4- else if there is not a match in the mainfile.csv write that record from the inputfile.csv to the mainfile.csv

Comment: Can you post what the mailfile.csv and inputfile.csv look like?  I personally wouldn't even attempt to write this in vbscript or batch. I'd use python.

Comment: Also, do the ordering of the records matter?

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `Scripting.Dictionary` to record each line in `mainfile.csv`. Then, to see if a line in `inputfile.csv` is new, all it takes is to see if that line exists in the dictionary. For example:

**mainfile.csv**

```
exists,one
exists,two
exists,three
exists,four
exists,five
```

**inputfile.csv**

```
exists,two
new,one
exists,four
new,two
new,three
```

**mainfile.csv** *(after running the program)*

```
exists,one
exists,two
exists,three
exists,four
exists,five
new,one
new,two
new,three
```

**Here's the code:**

---

```vb
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 4, ForAppending = 8

Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oDict : Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'
' Read the contents of 'mainfile.csv'. Add each line to a dictionary
' to allow for a quick lookup.
'
Dim oFileMain : Set oFileMain = oFso.OpenTextFile("mainfile.csv", ForReading)
Dim sLine
While Not oFileMain.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = oFileMain.ReadLine()
    oDict.Add sLine, True
Wend
oFileMain.Close
Set oFileMain = Nothing

'
' Re-open 'mainfile.csv' in append mode.
'
Set oFileMain = oFso.OpenTextFile("mainfile.csv", ForAppending)

'
' Read the contents of 'inputfile.csv'. Write a line to 'mainfile.csv'
' only if that line does not exist in the dictionary.
'
Dim oFileInput : Set oFileInput = oFso.OpenTextFile("inputfile.csv", ForReading)
While Not oFileInput.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = oFileInput.ReadLine()
    If Not oDict.Exists(sLine) Then  ' not a duplicate!
        WScript.Echo "Found new line: [" & sLine & "]"
        oFileMain.WriteLine sLine
    End If
Wend
oFileInput.Close
Set oFileInput = Nothing

'
' Wrap it up.
'
oFileMain.Close
Set oFileMain = Nothing

Set oDict = Nothing
Set oFso = Nothing

' End
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best attempt at doing it in python, not knowing the structure of the files:

```
with open("mainfile.csv", "r") as main:
    records = [x.strip() for x in main.readlines()]
with open("inputfile.csv", "r") as input:
    inputs = [x.strip() for x in input.readlines()]
for input in inputs:
    if input not in records:
        records.append(input)
with open("mainfile.csv", "w") as main:
    for record in records:
        main.write(record + "\n")
```

So for the following files you start with this:

inputfile.csv:

```
A quick brown fix
Two turtle doves
Feather boa
```

mainfile.csv:

```
Some other stuff
Two turtle doves
Friends in low places
Feather boa
Another Fairly boring thing
```

After you run the script mainfile.csv looks like this:

```
Some other stuff
Two turtle doves
Friends in low places
Feather boa
Another Fairly boring thing
A quick brown fix
```

Comment: jgritty, here is the structure of both .csv files...............................................................1,00000,00000,000000,000000,00000,00000
2,111111,111111,111111,111111,111111,111111
3,333333,333333,333333,333333,333333,333333

Comment: My python script will work fine on that data.  I apologize I can't do it in vbscript.